# Getting error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

it's cause an error, have no idea how to fix this /Car.java:17: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

```
public class Car { 
    private int year;
    private String model;  
    private String color;

Car(int yr, String m, String c){
    year = yr;
    model = m;
    color = c; 
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println(year + ", " + model + ", " + color);
} 
private class Cardemo { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car("2014", "SEDAN", "BLACK");
        }
}

private class Color { 
    enum Colors { 
        RED, BLUE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLACK, WHITE
    };
}

private class Model {
    enum Models {
        SEDAN, SUV, CONVERTIBLE, HATCHBACK
    };
 }
}
```

The result I wanted is "2014, SEDAN, BLACK" but it says string cannot be converted into int

Comment: Your code is incorrectly formatted making it very hard to read. Please fix the format.

Answer (score 3):

`new Car("2014", "SEDAN", "BLACK")`

The first parameter of the constructor is expected to be an integer but you are passing a string to it. Use an integer.

Comment: Note to reader: `"2014"`, having double quotes, is a `String` literal; while `2014`, without quotes, is an `int` literal